# Difference between "passing reference after assigning an object" and "passing object using new keyword" to a method in java?

Tags: java, oop, object, reference

What difference does it makes?

Let's think we have a method in java as following:

```
void demoMethod(MyClass mc){
    // some operations
}
```

First type:

```
demoMethod(new MyClass()); // directly passing  an object
```

Second type:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
demoMethod(mc); // passing reference of an object
```

Comment: The only difference is that you can use `mc` later.

Comment: No difference other than mc being declared as a seperate variable. You are still passing in the value of the reference to that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference in terms of the method's behavior on that reference. The first code can semantically translate to the second one. Eventually, the object created using `new MyClass()` needs to be stored somewhere so that it can be re-loaded and passed to the method.

However, using the second code you can re-use the reference.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any difference for `demoMethod`. Actually in both cases you are passing reference only.

However if you want to use the information after `demoMethod` does some operation in the calling method, you can't do that in first type.

Assume your `demoMethod` sets a property of your `MyClass` object to true or false, you don't have any way to find out what it's value is set to.

So, you can do something like

```
demoMethod(mc);
if(mc.isMyProperty()==true)
   System.out.println("mc is changed");
```